# Symfony2 profiler - where do i find form data?

Tags: symfony, profiler

I've got a form I'm trying to make in symfony2. When I'm trying to submit it, it displays the "this field cannot be empty" error, but by no field, since every field is filled out. In symfony1.4, there was a section in debug panel that displayed everything about the form, including why it wasn't validated. Can i find something like that in Symfony2 profiler, or is it just full of unusable request data, logs, and broken functionalities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form data can be found on the request panel.

However most likely you are posting a form and redirecting elsewhere, and when you access the Profiler directly from the toolbar, you are only viewing the request after the post request.

The quickest way is to go into the Profiler, click on "View All" up the top, and find the POST request that handled your form submission.

The alternative, you can enable `intercept-redirects`:

> When intercept-redirects is set to true, the web profiler intercepts the redirects and gives you the opportunity to look at the collected data before following the redirect.

See more here: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/internals.html#configuration

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, I noticed the part where sent data are detailed, but I need to get validation data - i need to find out why the form didn't validate. in symfony1.4, it was in view layer in debug panel. i can't find anything like that in profiler, so where can i find it?

Comment: I can't find anywhere that allows for form introspection, probably because its just an arbitrary variable and they expect the validation it returns is enough to determine the why. [Check this for other ways to access the error messages](http://php-opensource-help.blogspot.com.au/2011/07/how-to-get-all-form-error-in-symfony.html).